# Mediacodec stops automatically while encoding and decoding video in background and switching activities

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediacodec

I am using MediaCodec to change the resolution of video so that the size of the video can be reduced. I am following the process of extraction, decoding, encoding, muxing. If I remain on the same screen then it works fine. But switching activities stops the execution and the output video is created with a shorter duration.
The task of changing resolution of a video is started by a service.

How does changing the activities or restarting application affect the execution in a separate service.

Comment: Did you use bindService() or startService() function to start the service? And also, is it a foreground service?

Comment: yup, its a foreground service and I used startService() to start the video resolution change service.

Comment: Are you calling startForeground() in onStartCommand method of your service? Without this call, the service may be killed anytime by the OS.